# Raspberry Pi analog read

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, raspberry-pi

Trying to get the value from Arduino analog pin 0 to be shown as a live value in Tkinter but I'm new to Python.

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
from time import sleep

board = Arduino ('/dev/ttyUSB0')
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

 ------------------------BOTTOM of the code----------------------------------
 root = Tk()
 frame = Frame(root,height=500,width=500)
 frame.pack()
 root.title("Relay Controle")
 # Raspsberry output pin 11 / relay
 relayButton = Button(root, text="Turn RELAY On", command=relay)
 relayButton.place(x=10,y=2,)
 # Arduino maga: led button
 ledButton = Button(root, text="Turn LED pin 13 On", command=led )
 ledButton.place(x=130,y=2,)
 # value print out
 # Quit Button
 quitButton = Button(root, text="Quit", command=func1 )
 quitButton.place(x=444,y=470,)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: so you know how to read the analog pin? and all you want to do is update a text field in Tkinter?

Comment: is it like this?,  board.analog[0].read, 
yes update with the value from pin 0

Comment: ok so your question is really "how do i update a Label in tkinter every X seconds"? right? the GPIO nonsense is really just confusing your actual problem (since that is not the problem)... your current title implies that reading the analog pin is the part you dont know how to do\

Comment: i cant post the hole code, its complaining abut add more details.... 

my problem is i dont know how to read pin0 arduino, and get it print in the window, as and updatet value, it for a temperature sensor,

Comment: yeah .... I answered it below ...

Comment: i just posted the my hole Tk code up there,as it is now and working with buttons, sorry im a little stupid to understand,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root,height=500,width=500)
frame.pack()
my_label = StringVariable()
label = Label(frame,textvariable=my_label)
label.pack()
def updateLabel():
    my_label.set("%0.2f"%board.analog[0].read()))
    root.after(100,updateLabel)
root.after(100,updateLabel)
root.title("Relay Controle")
```

this just calls updateLabel every 100 miliseconds ...
updateLabel then refreshes the stringvariable with the new value from the analog read ...

per the docs to read an analog pin

```
#setup to recieve analog data
it = util.iterator(board)
it.start()
board.analog[0].enable_reporting()
# later to read
board.analog[0].read()
```

or you get an instance of the analog pin early

```
analog_0 = board.get_pin(’a:0:i’)
#then later you can read it
analog_0.read()
```

so my guess is maybe you arenot doing that setup part

Comment: what to put in StringVariable() ?

Comment: i get this erro then,
`File "/home/pi/testmappe/arduino2.py", line 87, in updateLabel
    var.set('%0.2f'%(board.analog[0].read()))
TypeError: float argument required, not NoneType`

Comment: so you are getting None back from the read .... I assumed that you were reading the value correctly .... I have no idea about pyfirmata ... I guess I could go look at the docs

Comment: thanks ! it running now, if want to use spinbox, to controle when a relay is on or off, when the analog reading is a specific value,   whit def relayon_value(): or how do i work that out ?